# If $\mu$ is a probability measure and we have $\iint e^{-|x-y|}\mu(dx) \mu(dy)=1$ then why is there a $c'$ with $\int e^{-|x-c'|} \mu(dx)\ge 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a one-dimensional probability measure and we have 
$$\iint e^{-|x-y|}\mu(dx) \mu(dy)=1.$$

Then why is there a $c'$ with $$\int e^{-|x-c'|} \mu(dx)\ge 1 \;(=1 \; \text{in fact})$$ since $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Also, why does this mean that $\mu$ is concentrated at $c'$ since $e^{-|x-c'|}<1$ for $x\neq c'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$f(y) := \int e^{-|x-y|} \mu(dx).$$ You know that $$\int f(y) \mu(dy) = 1.$$
Let's prove the statment indirectly and assume that for almost every $y \in \Omega$ we have $f(y) < 1$. Then
$$\int_{} f(y) \mu(dy) < \int \mu(dy) = \mu(\Omega) = 1. $$
A contradiction. This means that the set $\{y \in \Omega: f(y) \geq 1\}$ has nonzero measure, hence can not be empty. For the second question, let $f(c')=1$ and assume $\mu(\Omega \setminus \{c'\}) > 0.$ We find that
$$ 1 = \int_{\Omega} e^{-|x-c'|}\mu(dx) = \mu(\{c'\}) + \int_{\Omega \setminus \{c'\}} e^{-|x-c'|}\mu(dx) < \mu(\{c'\}) + \mu(\Omega\setminus\{c'\}) = 1 $$
A contradiction. Hence, $\mu(\{c'\}) = 1$.

Comment: But when we have $f(y)<1$ a.e., then don't we get $\int f(y)dy \le \int 1 dy$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66370/strict-monotonicity-of-integral

Comment: I still haven't answered your second question though.

Comment: Right, I thought it would work with the same argument. But seems like there needs to be a little adaptation. Would appreciate your answer!

Comment: I extended my original answer in order to adress the second question as well.