Contraposition of $h>0 \implies \int h d\mu=0 \quad \mu-\text{a.e.}$
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and $f, g$ two non-negative measurable functions. To show that $f<g$ implies $\int f d\mu < \int g d\mu$ one often shows the equivalent contrapositive statement. Contraposition is defined via $A\implies B \iff \neg B \implies \neg A$. To this end, one defines $h:=g-f$ which again is a non-negative measurable function. Given our assumption that $f<g$, $h$ is even strictly positive. So what we need to show is $h>0 \implies \int h d\mu >0$. Now this statement is usually proven via contraposition. The contraposition statement is: Let $h\geq 0$, then
$$\int h d\mu = 0 \implies h=0 \quad \mu-\text{a.e.} $$
What I  dont understand about this statement are the following two things: So first of all why do (or can) we assume that $h\geq 0$? As I have written before $h:=g-f>0$ and then the negation would give us $\int h d\mu \leq 0 \implies h\leq 0$
As for the second question: Why is the negation of the statement $h>0$ (for $h\geq 0$)
$$h=0 \quad \mu-\text{a.e.} $$
I.e., where does the almost everywhere come from? I mean from measure theory its clear that from the integral being zero we can only deduce an almost everywhere statement, but by just blindly applying $A\implies B \iff \neg B \implies \neg A$ and hence by just forming the negation of $h>0$ I dont understand where the almost everywhere comes from

Note that the negation of "$h>0$" isn't "$h\leq 0$".  It would be if $h$ were just a number, but it's not: $h$ is a function.

So we can also write $h>0$ more formally as $\forall x: h(x)>0 $. Hence, the negation would be $\exists x: h(x)\leq 0$ is that correct?

To be both clear and candid, I reject your assertion that $h>0 \implies \int h\,d\mu > 0$ is usually proven by the contrapositive.
In fact, I've probably never seen this proven that way.

A better symbolic representation of the proof is
$$h \geq 0 \implies \left( \mu(\{x : h(x)>0\})>0 \implies \int h\,d\mu > 0\right)$$
As a corollary, we have $h>0 \implies \int h\, d\mu > 0$.
Coincidentally, the usual proof at this stage is direct.  The only place the contrapositive shows its head is with the step $$\mu(\{x : h(x)>0\})>0 \implies \exists r \Big(r>0 \land \mu(\{x : h(x)\geq r\})>0\Big),$$
for which the contrapositive is typically easier to show.

Thanks for your answer! Here is an example where this statement is proven by contraposition:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66374/613148

@guest1 We're pushing the envelope on what is considered "proven by contraposition" if we accept that.  It would seem more appropriate to say he's proving $$h \geq 0 \implies \left( \int h,d\mu \leq 0 \implies \mu({x : h(x)>0})=0\right)$$ where you might notice the "inner" conditional is the contrapositive of that in my representation.  (Note that in light of the given, non-strict version, the integral can't be negative, so $\leq 0$ becomes $=0$)
